# Day of the month in statsmodels MSTL

Tags: statsmodels

I'm trying to establish if there is a way to use MSTL to get the seasonal index for the day-of-the-month.

Some analysis shows behaviour where we can see spikes at the beginning and end of the month alongside hourly and weekly.

MSTL allows you to do this accordingly.

```
>>> from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import MSTL
>>> res = MSTL(data, periods=(24, 24*7)).fit()
>>> res.plot()
>>> plt.tight_layout()
>>> plt.show
```

https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.MSTL.html

But when it comes to day of the month. They cannot be broken down into a neat number of days 28, 30 & 31 accordingly.

Is there a means to implement it?
Or does one need to modify the input data to make it work?
Or you add a add a separate index on top of what is generated?